# Exporting NDWI time series using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, time-series, normalized-difference-water-index

This is the code I have written:

```js
// start and end dates
var startDate = '2021-11-01';
var endDate = '2023-07-31';

// dataset
var collection = landsat9.filterDate(startDate, endDate);

// bounds
var shp = geometry;

// create clip collection function
var clipToShp = function(image) {
  var clipped = image.clip(shp);
  return clipped;
};

// clip all images to this shp
var clippedCollection = collection.map(clipToShp);


// function to get montly image for each year
var getMonthlyImage =function (date) {
  date = ee.Date(date);
  var imgDate = collection
    .filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'month'))
    .mean();
  return imgDate.visualize({
    min: -1,
    max: 1,
    // bands: ['B3', 'B5'],
    palette: ['00FFFF', '0000FF']
  });
}

// get the list of imagery for each month
var monthDiff = ee.Date(startDate).advance(1, 'month').millis().subtract(ee.Date(startDate).millis());
var listMap = ee.List.sequence(ee.Date(startDate).millis(), ee.Date(endDate).millis(), monthDiff);

// get the collection from the list
 collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listMap.map(function(dateMillis) {
  var date = ee.Date(dateMillis);
  return getMonthlyImage(date);
}));


// create ndwi of collection function
var ndwiOfCollection = function(image) {
  var ndwiOfImage = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B4']);
  return ndwiOfImage.copyProperties(image);
};

// create a collection of ndwi
var ndwiCollection = clippedCollection.map(ndwiOfCollection);

// create a feature to iterate through it later
var fet = ee.Feature(shp);

// add ndwi timeseries to the shp
var addPropNDWI = function(image, feature) {
  var newf = ee.Feature(feature);
  var featureNDWI = ee.Number(image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), shp));
  var theDate = image.get('DATE_ACQUIRED');//.format(Y-M-D);
  var ndwiDate = ee.String('NDWI').cat(theDate);
  return ee.Feature(newf.set(ndwiDate, featureNDWI));
};

var featNDWI = ee.Feature(ndwiCollection.iterate(addPropNDWI, fet));

// make a collection of the features
var featureCollectionNdwi = ee.FeatureCollection([featNDWI]);

// map settings
Map.centerObject(shp);

// display the feature
Map.addLayer(featureCollectionNdwi, {}, 'featureCollectionNdwi');

// export index
Export.video.toDrive({
  collection: featureCollectionNdwi,
  description: 'NDWI_Export',
  dimensions: 360,
  framesPerSecond: 1,
  region: shp,
  maxPixels: 10000000
});
```

However when I am exporting I get the error saying there is a lot of pixels despite setting the maxPixels value to 10000000.

Any ideas?